# Dax measure to get 2 columns from different tables into one

Tags: powerbi, dax, rdbms, daxstudio

I have 5 tables;

1. member : 1 to many relation with product and cash transactions.
2. product : 1 to many with product transaction history.
3. cash transactions: many to one with date.
4. product transactions: many to 1 with the date.
5. date
   I want to create a measure with the member id(Not the primary key) wherein I can see all the cash and product transaction without any aggregation.

I tried making 2 variable to use them but I can make them appear in one column